# Regex to extract IP address from hyphenated string

Tags: regex

I have a string of text that contains an IP address with hyphens and words. I want to extract the IP address from it using a regular expression that also converts the hyphens to periods.

So to clarify, can the IP address be extracted and the hyphens be replaced with periods **purely with a regular expression** without using the regex in some code such as Java or Python:

**What I have**

```
ip-10-179-50-22.corp.dept.org.uk
```

**What I want**

```
10.179.50.22
```

I'm thinking that I need to extract 4 groups based on numbers and concatenate them with periods, but I have no idea how to do this or **if this is even possible with only regex**?

**What I've tried**

```
(\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}-\d{2,3})
```

This gives me back `10-179-50-22` but I don't know how to replace on the matching group.

### EDIT

I edited the question to clarify that I was trying to find a solution to find and replace with only a regular expression.

In summary, it looks like you can't just use a regex, but the regex needs to used with some code to achieve this

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment @WiktorStribiżew - the section above called 'What I've tried' is my code attempt

Comment: How to replace is language-specific. Which language are you using?

Comment: There is only a regex string. Where are you using it? How? If you type the regex in Notepad++, it won't do anything, you need to put it into a specific field in a specific window. If you write it down on a Web page, but do not use it in any code, you won't get the job done either. Regex is *a piece of text*. It describes some specific text pattern. It depends on the code that uses the regex what it finally does.

Comment: I was attempting this on on https://regex101.com/  This will end up inside an ansible jinja2 file which I believe is interpreted by Python

Comment: That is important. So, try `| regex_replace('.*?(\\d{1,3})-(\\d{1,3})-(\\d{1,3})-(\\d{1,3}).*', '\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4')`

Comment: Regexes find text patterns. They do not transform the text they match. You can match `10-179-50-22` with a regex but you can't transform it into `10.179.50.22`.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know which language your using but a lot of them have a .replace() with which you could change - for . or event sub string with a bit of adjusting should work for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was hoping for a pure regex to do this.  Is it even possible?

Comment: To my knowledge you still need a replace method() but it may vary between the technologies you might be using. Insight on your project might help use find a solution

Answer (score 1):

See [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/llwdoL/1).

Regex:

```py
.*\b(\d{2,3})-(\d{2,3})-(\d{2,3})-(\d{2,3})\b.*
```

Substitution:

```py
\1.\2.\3.\4
```

Result:

```py
10.179.50.22
```

Note that I am just using the regex you provided to match the IP address part, rather than a more accurate regex that would match any valid IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the sed command, this regex would do the job. It uses 4 groups like you suggested.

```
sed -i 's/^ip-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\).*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g'
```

It replaces `ip-10-179-50-22.corp.dept.org.uk` with `10.179.50.22`.
You can test it on https://sed.js.org.